# How to read linux-style function names?

Tags: c, linux, function

I'm seeing a style very different that what I first learned.  I'm accustomed to doing as much as I can to make code read like plain english.  Practically what that means is starting most function names with an imperative verb:

Makes sense:

```
DoWorkOnA();
DoWorkOnB();
```

But now as I play around with more lower level code in the linux kernel and on functions from [this](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF51_SDK/nRF51_SDK_v8.x.x/doc/8.1.0/s110/html/index.html) SDK, I'm seeing more of:

No sense:

```
a_work_do();
b_work_do();
```

**Is there any logic behind this jumble of nouns and verbs?**  It seems like the verb is always placed last in some weird [Yodic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda) way.  I can understand prefixing public functions to prevent name conflicts, but this seems to be much deeper than a prefix:

Makes sense:

```
MODULEA_DoWork();
MODULEB_DoWork();
```

Learning to read other people's code is an important part of growing as a developer.  I'm just trying to understand how I can more-quickly read what seems to be a jumble of words.

The example of `add_work()` makes sense in this [style guide.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle)

Comment: Yes, 'camel case' is C++, not C. Traditionally, C uses lower case, with upper case reserved for the system `defines`, etc. As for naming, what is generaly done is functional naming. If you are operating on strings and converting, then you see examples like (e.g. `strrol` (string to long), or `strtod` (string to double)). It follows to the variable naming conventions as well. What the heck `a_` or `b_` means? Who know, but for the kernel devs it would make sense if it were some type of binary choice between doing work on `a` or `b`. It's just a matter of style.

Comment: If `DoWorkOnA();` makes sense to you in C#. then I'd write `doWorkOnA()` in Java, and `do_work_on_a()` in C or C++. If you're interested, look at the [Linux Coding Style Guidelines](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Comment: Using the module or type that a function acts on as the prefix for the function name means that all functions related to the module or data type will show up in lists grouped together.  I think this is a major reason for that naming convention.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, this is probably not half of the story. Prefix naming is usually used to avoid naming conflicts between different modules, such that you can add a function to one part without interfering with the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any logic behind this jumble of nouns and verbs?

Sure there is.

```
a_work_do()
```

refers to subject `a`, object `work`, action `do` (relating the two latter).

There could be much more like this which then would sort nicely on subject and object:

```
a_work_create()
a_work_do()
a_work_cleanup()
```

or

```
me_book_buy()
me_book_read()
me_book_giveaway()
```

and so on ...

Yoda, is a smart guy, isn't he? ;-)